# array out of index error - jacobi method implementation

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

```
public class testrun {


    public static  double ellipticalequn(float x, float y){
         double exp;
         exp=(-2)*Math.exp(Math.pow((y-(.35*6.5)),2)-Math.pow((x-(.75*8)),2)/(2*.05*6.5));
         return exp;
     }
     public static void jacobi(){
         int ny=80;
        int nx=80;
         double[][][] p=new double[100][100][100];
         for(int i=0;i<100;i++){p[i][i][0]=0;} //initialise
         for(int i=0;i<nx;i++){
             p[0][i][0]=10;                 //Boundary conditions
             p[79][i][0]=10;
             p[i][79][0]=50;
             p[i][0][0]=50;

        }
         boolean loop=true;
         int k=0;
         while(loop){
             double error=0;
             for(int i=1;i<nx-1;i++){
                 for(int j=1;j<ny-1;j++){
                     p[i][j][k]=0.25*((p[i-1][j][k]+p[i+1][j][k]+p[i][j+1][k]+p[i][j-1][k])-ellipticalequn((float)i,(float)j));
                     error+=Math.pow(p[i][j][k],2);
                 }
             }
             error=Math.sqrt(error);
             k++;
             if(k>50){
                 loop=false;}

             if(error<(10^(-8))){loop=false;}
             else { loop=true;}
         }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
            jacobi();

        }
}
```

---

i have spent 3 hours and am unable to figure out the error! please please help me here!
the error shows up but i dont know why it does.i am new to java.
thanks 
aadi

Comment: what is the error , would you post the error too , please ?

Comment: If you spent 3 hours trying to figure out the problem spend a few more minutes posting the stacktrace...

Comment: I'd highly recommend cleaning up your code some - the indentation is inconsistent, there are some places (like where you set `p[i][j][k]`) that should really be split into at least separate lines if not separate methods, and there is a lot of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants). There are no comments either. It makes it difficult to help if we have trouble understanding your code.

Comment: if you are using tool like eclise just try to debug. Also stacktrace will tell you at what line error is thrown  so debugging by putting debug pointer around tat may help.

Answer (score 0):

You get the array index out of bounds exception because in your loop:

```
 boolean loop=true;
 int k=0;
 while(loop){
     double error=0;
     for(int i=1;i<nx-1;i++){
         for(int j=1;j<ny-1;j++){
             p[i][j][k]=0.25*((p[i-1][j][k]+p[i+1][j][k]+p[i][j+1][k]+p[i][j-1][k])-ellipticalequn((float)i,(float)j));
             error+=Math.pow(p[i][j][k],2);
         }
     }
     error=Math.sqrt(error);
     k++;
     if(k>50){
         loop=false;}

     if(error<(10^(-8))){loop=false;}
     else { loop=true;}
 }
```

you are not checking that k never gets bigger than 99 (which, if fact, does and when it gets to 100 you get the exception). I'm not familiar with the Jacobi algorithm, but if you intended to leave the loop when k hits the value of 50, then just add a `break;` command in your if statement. so you've got two solutions, first: change that if statement to:

```
if(k>50){
   loop=false;
   break;
}
```

Second, check again for k not being bigger than 100 after you check the error:

```
if(error<(10^(-8)))
    loop=false;
else if(k < 100)
    loop=true;
```